# What counts as a death?

Tags: resident-evil-6

At the end of each chapter you get a ranking page of which one criteria is the number of deaths, but what counts as a death?

I know this may seem obvious, however I have just completed chapter 5 of Chris's campaign and it tells me I have 3 deaths - the problem is I had "game over" more than 3 times. Most of the deaths occurred during action sequences (where you mainly run and avoid obstacles) so I am wondering if these count? Also, I think one of the action sequences was mostly my partner dying - so perhaps these do not count?

Can anybody confirm this?

Comment: Can you not play a chapter and count the ways you die and see if it tallies? I would assume it counts any time that results in the 'YOU ARE DEAD' screen...

Comment: @Alex: Providing I don't get an answer any time soon, I will at some point count the deaths for a chapter that has some action sequences and see what numbers I get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only counts as a death for you, if the character you play dies in the short death cutscene. If the other character dies (bot or player controlled), it will count to the death of your partner.
This makes sense in the way, that you cannot be hold responsible for the inability of your coop-partner. On the other hand, it is ridicoulous, seeing as the survival of your partner depends on your actions in some sequences.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. Perhaps Capcom were concerned with players getting frustrated with AI bugs/mistakes when trying for 'S' ranks on harder difficulties. One a the most annoying things is to be working so hard for something, and have it taken away by an AI flaw. I prefer to be in control of my own mistakes, with nobody else to blame